# Microphone for DELL Optiplex 7080 Desktop

Tags: drivers

I have a new dell desktop optiplex 7080 that will not take a voice input from a headset that I have plugged to it. So far, I have visited the manufacturer's website and supplied the service tag then installed the audio driver matching my device model and this does not seem to solve the issue. I have minimal experience regarding hardware configuration but would appreciate a guide on what to do to have this new dell model pick or recognize a Microphone

Comment: This is on Windows, right?  Does the headset appear under "Audio inputs and outputs" in the Device Manager?

Comment: Desktop typically have one connector for input and another for output. If your headset has a combo plug then you need a splitter, that's all.

Comment: What kind of connector does the headset have?  USB?

Comment: The headset has the usual audio plug and the optiplex 7080 has Windows 10 installed. I can see it in the audio input and output but it wont just pick a voice input. @ChanganAuto how do I handle this for a headset with a single plug.

Comment: Search for "3.5mm audio splitter"

Comment: This finally worked. The front audio jack expected a 4-pin jack to function as a headset, and I had been using a 3-pin jack all the while